# distplot depreciated. Trying to use function to create multiple plots using displot or histplot

Tags: python, seaborn, data-visualization, deprecated

I created a function to plot multiple columns using distplot but it looks like it is now depreciated. error:  Please adapt your code to use either `displot` (a figure-level function with similar flexibility) or `histplot` (an axes-level function for histograms).

Can someone please help me update this code.
Here is the code:

```
def creating_distplot(size,data,features):                
    plt.figure(figsize=size)
    for i in range(len(features)):
        plt.subplot(5,3,i +1)
        sns.distplot(data[features[i]])


num_vars = ad_df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object', 'datetime64']).columns
creating_distplot((16,18), ad_df, num_vars)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ukulg.png)

Comment: You could just use `sns.histplot(data[features[i]], kde=True)` instead of `sns.distplot(...)`.  Note that the deprecation isn't an error but a warning.  For the current version, `distplot` keeps working as before (apart from also showing the warning that it will disappear in future versoins).

Comment: Thank yop! I am not sure why I didn't try that in the first place and thank you for clarifying the error and warning